# Parallelism in Spouts

Tags: apache-storm

New to Storm and just understanding the concept of Spouts and how to achieve parallelism in them.

I have defined a Spout A and have set 3 tasks and 3 executors and 1 Bolt(Lets not worry about Bolt). Lets assume each of the spout task 
is assigned a dedicated worker. That means there are 3 spouts ready to receive a Stream. A message or stream (say X) enters the topology. How is this handled in the Spout?

a. Will all the spouts receive the stream A ? If yes, then all the 3 spouts will process it and the same message is processed multiple times right?
b. Who will decide in above case which spout should receive this stream?
c. Is it possible to balance the load across the spouts? 
d. Is it that there should be only one spout in the topology ?

P.S: Consider  this is general spout, not to confuse with the Kafka spouts.

Answer (score 1):

Storm is just a frame, your questions are basically determined by implementation of spout code. So,sadly, there is no way to consider "general spout". We have to discuss some specific spout.

Let's take kafka spout for example. Basically, it has no difference with normal kafka consumer. Kafka spout has a logic to distribute partitions to different spout tasks, and load balance is also handled at this period, one partition will be consumed by only one spout task,so there will be no multiple data.